# Wireless USB adapter AWUS036NHA is recognized by Debian 9 but doesn't connect to network

Tags: wireless-networking, debian

I installed `firmware-atheros` in a Lenovo T450s, Debian 9, the system shows the wifi networks recognized by **AWUS036NHA** but doesn't connect to any of them.

The same thing happens when I try to connect to another router. The internal wifi interface works fine.

I have installed KDE Neon in the same laptop on another partition and the **AWUS036NHA** works fine there.

How can I fix this issue on Debian 9?